# PKCS12 to JKS conversion in WebLogic

Tags: ssl-certificate, middleware, weblogic12c

For SpringBoot application we are using PKCS12 and then converting to JKS for Certificate renewal. But in WebLogic why PKCS12 to JKS conversion not working? Anyone having idea?

Is there anyway to create PKCS12 and converting to JKS in WebLogic?

P12 to JKS conversion not accepting in WebLogic. Why

Comment: WebLogic Server does accept PKCS12 keystores. What is your WebLogic Server version ?

Comment: 12.2.1.4 - could you pls let me know the procedure

Comment: What do you need exactly ? Create a keystore ? Configure WebLogic ?